# Pincipal Component Analysis error

Tags: r

I keep getting this error when I try to run a Principal Component Analysis -

```
Final_Dataset <- Final_Dataset[, colSums(is.na(Final_Dataset)) != nrow(Final_Dataset)]

Final_Dataset  <- Final_Dataset[,-grep("Date|factor|character|logical", sapply(Final_Dataset, class))]

table(sapply(Final_Dataset, class))
nzv <- nearZeroVar(Final_Dataset, saveMetrics = TRUE)
print(paste('range:', range(nzv$percentUnique)))
dim(nzv[nzv$percentUnique > 0.1,])
gisette_nzv <- Final_Dataset[c(rownames(nzv[nzv$percentUnique > 0.1,]))]

pmatrix <- scale(gisette_nzv)
princ <- prcomp(pmatrix)
```

> Error in svd(x, nu = 0) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Is there any way of telling the function to omit na? The problem here is the dataset is huge so if I remove nas there will be no rows left, because out of the ~1000 there are always rows with missing values.

Comment: Two interesting links: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35561/imputation-of-missing-values-for-pca and https://francoishusson.wordpress.com/2017/08/05/can-we-believe-in-the-imputations/

Comment: @MarcoSandri thanks!